# How to match exactly 5 digit number with preg match?

Tags: php, preg-match

What I currently have,

```
$file = "1234123412341234 | 11218 | 9178814202";
preg_match('/(?P<5digit>[0-9]{5})$/D', $file, $match);
echo $match["5digit"];
```

Basically I want it to grab "11218". But instead it's grabbing 14202 from the other line. Is there any way to just get it to match exactly 5 digits and nothing else?

Comment: you just need the number between two pipe `|`? e.g 11218

Comment: Pretty much, but it won't always be like that so I'm just trying to figure out how to grab exactly a 5 digit number...

Comment: Because you putted a ending `$` sign, where from you want the 5 digits, from starging/ending/in beteen two pipe`|`?

Comment: Where would I put it?

Comment: I just need to find out how to grab a 5 digit number in preg match.

Comment: then just try `(?<= )[0-9]{5}(?= )`, that's it or with boundary `\b[0-9]{5}\b` but I think with your $file string it is possible with simple `explode()`

Comment: Try `\b[0-9]{5}\b` or to be more specific `\| *\K[0-9]{5}(?= *\|)`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/bY0VkI/1

Comment: If I use /[0-9]{5}/ then it grabs 12341 from the first part... It needs to grab an EXACT string that is ONLY 5 digits long.

Comment: @revo I LOVE YOU. I spent like two hours trying to figure out how to get that to work...